# store data in a variable into a field in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a sub in Access, that creates a folder based on user name, but i want to know is, how I can save the file path into a field in a table.

this is my code and I want to save`strFolder` into a field called `ImageFilePath` in table `Table_Users`

```
Private Sub btnSaveClose_Click()
Const strParent = "\\dlreng01\Roberts$\Access\Images\"
Dim struserID As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim fso As Object
' Get user ID from control
struserID = Me.UserName
' Full path
strFolder = strParent & struserID
' Create FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Check whether folder exists
If fso.FolderExists(strFolder) = False Then
    ' If not, create it
    fso.CreateFolder strFolder
End If
' Open it
Shell "explorer.exe " & strFolder, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
Public Sub Test()

    AddFilePath "MyFilePath"  'strParent & struserID

End Sub

Public Sub AddFilePath(strFolder As String)

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table_Users", dbOpenDynaset)
    With rst
        .AddNew
        .Fields("ImageFilePath") = strFolder
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, as i cant get this function to work, the code executes and there are no errors, but it doesnt copy the file path into the field, i have placed both functions into the relevant form VBA.